# Automatically set password for user - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

[Following this tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up), I setup a simple registration system with devise, where a user enters their email address, they are sent a confirmation email, they click on it, it takes them to a form where they have to enter their password and complete the registration.

**How do I skip that password form so that once the user clicks on the confirmation link in their email, their account is created? How can I automatically set simple password for all users?**

Comment: I'd put an `after_create` hook in your `User` model to set the default password. But as for skipping the password input, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method in your user model to use it instead of the `create` method. Let's call it `create_with_password`

```
def self.create_with_password(attr={})
   generated_password = attr[:first_name] + "123"
   self.create(attr.merge(password: generated_password, password_confirmation: generated_password))
end
```

Override devise's registration controller to use your new method which generates the two necessary fields for devise `password` and `password_confirmation` using the `first_name` attribute in your user model for example then `123` like in `John123`

In your controller after your parameters are sanitized. You should call `User.create_with_password(user_params)`

Comment: Actually it's better to use `generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)` for a generated password

Comment: I would personally like to generate some thing more memory friendly strong entropy password with [xkpassword](https://github.com/jdeen/xkpassword)