# Overriding Devise's parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I just want to modify the value of the password parameter in

`Devise::SessionsController` my current code looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :override_params, only: [:create]

  private

  def override_params
    params[:user][:password] = '123123123'   
  end

end
```

In the code above, I'm trying to modify the value of user's password
but when I try to login, seems like it doesn't override the user password params. I'm still getting the value that I entered on the URL not the one I'm overridden in controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically set password for user - Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398803/automatically-set-password-for-user-devise)

Comment: @MayurShah this one is different. It's assigning a value to an ActiveRecord, not parameters

Comment: have you tried something like this: user.password = user.password_confirmation = password in override_params

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in) do |user_params|
      u_params = user_params.permit(:username, :email)
      u_params[:password] = '123123123'
      u_params.permit!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but still cannot modify the value of the password parameter. I think devise is user resource_params but I cannot modify the value of this. :(

Comment: can you provide more context as to what and why you need this? maybe there's something else that can be done

Comment: I'm creating an API to decrypt the password came from an API request of iOS app. So basically the iOS app will pass to me the encrypted password then on my end I need to decrypt it. I want to modify the user[:password] params to decrypted password, but I cannot override the value of it. The decryption part is already working I tested it on my rails console.

Comment: so you are using devise_token_auth, or just devise? You will have to override whole create action in sessions_controller in this case

Comment: I'm just using devise.